How can I format every cell value as text?
I have a c# winforms application where I open an excel and put every sheet inside a DataTable but I have a column that has both numbers and alphanumeric values and since excel formats columns based on the first 10 rows the datatable cells that contain letters are blank
This is the connection string that I use
OleDbConnection objConn = null;
System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txt_nomeFile.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text';";
objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
objConn.Open();
dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

Then I iterate trough all sheets and select their content like this
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";
ds.Clear();
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connString);
data.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];

Is there a way to format all cells as text so the values can be shown inside the datatable?

put a ' before every text: https://superuser.com/a/806795

The fact is that the user needs to upload his excel file, and most of the times they have thousands of records, I wanted to do something from code
